# How to solve for boundaries of Julia Sets?

Tags: complex-analysis, recreational-mathematics, fractals

I'm currently trying to create a fast OpenGL application that can render Julia Sets in real time. I was able to do this with the Mandelbrot Set, thanks to [this handy trick](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/Mandelbrot_set/mandelbrot#Cardioid_and_period-2_checking) to quickly identify period 1 and 2 regions. But when I moved over to Julia Sets, I realized quickly that I can't use the same formulas for optimization, as the final picture looked like a normal Julia set but only with a black Mandelbrot smack dab covering it in the middle. How can I do the same kind of simple optimization with any given Julia Set, with finding the boundaries of the first couple periodic regions?

Example: $c=-.13+-.8i$
[image]
https://www.marksmath.org/visualization/julia_sets/

Comment: Are you sure these inner regions exist for Julia sets? Can you add an image of a set with the inner regions coloured and parameters to generate such a set? Thanks.

Comment: I think It will be harder to find simple regions inside a julia set, maybe you can apply a quadtree similar to http://webdoc.sub.gwdg.de/ebook/serien/e/IMPA_A/721.pdf

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I put up an example to show which regions of the Julia set I want to be able to quickly identify

Comment: @rain1 Thanks for the reference! I looked at it, but I don't think it's suited for what I'm looking for as it takes far too much memory and is not suited for what I am looking for

Comment: You only need 2 bits per cell, and a mipmap chain needs 4/3 the memory of the biggest level, so memory should not really be an issue for the paper linked.